# Jade: dynamic image url

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm trying to set an image url in jade...

I have this: `img(src = 'http://192.168.1.8:8081')`

I need to change 192.168.1.8 automatically with the server address...

For example if I connect to my server from office, my url should become `img(src = 'http://myPUBLICserveraddress:8081')`

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this with Dust.js, but the principle should be the same.  The way I do this is to set a `hostname` and `port` attribute on the app for both development and production (which is assigned in `app.configure('development')` and `app.configure('production')`), and then in the templates, I just do the Dust.js equivalent of:

```
- if (port)
    img(src="http://#{host}:#{port}")
- else
    img(src="http://#{host}")
```

And I get what I'm looking for, which is the right link based on the environment (dev vs production).

Comment: You have to pass `host` and `port` to the template in the `.render()` call.  As I said, I store them for the whole app in my configuration, using `app.set('host', 'abc123.com')` or whatever.